# How should i classify the nested class given in this example?

Tags: java

I was going thru ThreadLocal class and found below example

```
public class UniqueThreadIdGenerator {

 private static final AtomicInteger uniqueId = new AtomicInteger(0);

 private static final ThreadLocal < Integer > uniqueNum = 
     new ThreadLocal < Integer > () {
         @Override protected Integer initialValue() {
             return uniqueId.getAndIncrement();
     }
 };

 public static int getCurrentThreadId() {
     return uniqueId.get();
 }
} // UniqueThreadIdGenerator
```

**Wondering the class ThreadLocal  created above should be classified as inner class/anonymous class? Not Sure.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an [anonymous subclass](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Nested_Classes#Anonymous_Classes) of `ThreadLocal`.

An [inner class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) is a class which is **declared** inside of another class declaration, using the `class` keyword. For example, `Bar` is an inner class of `Foo` below:

```
class Foo {
    int a;
    boolean b;

    class Bar {
        String s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt , as per anonymous class definition they are meant to be used for once and they dont have name. But here i can this class has name with uniqueNum variable (through its in  a different way ) and we can use refer this class multiple times with reference uniqueNum

Comment: **`uniqueNum` is not a class.** It's an instance of an anonymous class.

Answer (score 1):

It's anonymous because it doesn't have a name. Well, not one that has been explicitly created in code anyway, but that's beside the point.

Comment: +1 for hinting that to JVM there are no **anonymous** classes, they all have a name.

Comment: It might be something like `UniqueThreadIdGenerator$1` if memory serves me correctly. There will even be a class file generated with that name.